# Can't add stereotypes to toolbox page

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to create a custom toolbox with some stereotypes I created. I'm following this guide: https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/modeling_tools/create_toolbox_profiles_using_.html.

This is my profile diagram:
[image]

However, when I try to add the stereotypes to the toolbox page, I select them but then they don't get listed in the toolbox items...

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: can you add an image of your profile diagram, where you define the stereotype?

Comment: I've added it. It only has the stereotypes though...

Comment: That's the problem. You need to extend a meta-type, or specialize another stereotype for this to work (or both).

Comment: I've added a "Generalization" connection with a sysml1.4 block (see updated figure in the question) and still no luck

Comment: It's the extend to a UML metatype you need for the toolbox thing to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding the metaclass in the "Profile helper".

[image]

Here's the profile diagram view of a custom stereotype:

[image]