# Using stereotypes to enhance dimensional modelling

Tags: database-design, enterprise-architect, kimball

I am working on a star schema physical database model in Sparx EA

I'd like to tag tables as "Fact" or dimension, then I'd like to utilise this with a few features.

I've created two "stereotypes" from the "UML Types" menu called "Fact" and "Dimension" with base class = "class"

Then I've gone to the table in my model and added the new stereotype to the table. Now the stereotype is both "fact" and "EAUML::table"

I have a few objectives:
A. Make the tables visually different - DONE
B. In the "Matrix" view I'd like facts in rows and dimensions in columns (this gives me a Kimball enterprise bus matrix), however there doesn't seem to be a way to filter on stereotype in this view. I'm not sure what the "Type" drop down is a list of.
C. Also I've noticed that now the column order in the table is no longer honoured

Can anyone assist with items B and C?

Comment: This is the one that gave me hope I could ask this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370274/cant-add-stereotypes-to-toolbox-page  anyway I'm now a member of the Sparx page and here's my question if anyone comes across this. https://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,48264.0.html

Comment: You can in fact ask questions about EA here, but they have to be singular (only one question per question), and precise. A phrase like "can anyone assist me with..." is generally not received very well here. Try to phrase your question as "How do I do X with Y given Z and K"

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but more or less repeating what Geert told you on Sparx' forum:

`«EAUML::Table»` is a hog created by Sparx. It's special in many ways. They hard-doded quite some stuff and trying to inherit from it will fail (likely/in most cases). So You have to think of other ways. Creating your own stereotype is the probably only way (or something completely different?). Asking Sparx to open their code will likely be futile.